# Solving the diff eq $dy/dt= .5y\ln(100/y)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $$\frac{dy}{dt}=5y\ln\frac{100}{y}$$

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Isham's solution is probably the best way to go, also you can **directly integrate**:

$$\int \frac{dy}{y (\ln y-\ln 100)} = -\int0.5 dt \\
\ln(\ln y - \ln100) = -0.5t + C$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint

Substitute $y=e^z$

With $\frac {dy}{dt}= \frac {de^z}{dz}\frac {dz}{dt}=e^z\frac {dz}{dt}$

$$e^z\frac{dz}{dt}=5e^z(\ln(100)-z)$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=5(\ln(100)-z)$$
$$\int\frac{dz}{\ln(100)-z}=\int 5 \,dt=5t+K$$